# NHibernate query timing out

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate, timeout

I'm getting the following NHibernate timeout exception:

```
could not execute query
```

with the inner exception message being:

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

This is the NHibernate code that is failing:

```
shareClassReturns = _session.CreateCriteria<ShareClassTrailingReturn>()
        .Add(LambdaSubquery.Property<ShareClassTrailingReturn>(x => x.ShareClass.Id).In(GetAvailableShareClassIds()))
        .Add(LambdaSubquery.Property<ShareClassTrailingReturn>(x => x.ShareClass.Id).In(GetShareclassIdsInCalculationGroup(peerGroups, classificationTypes)))
        .Add<ShareClassTrailingReturn>(c => c.CurrencyId == "GBP")
        .AddShareClassReturnOrder(order)
        .CreateCriteria<ShareClassTrailingReturn>(scr => scr.ShareClass, JoinType.InnerJoin)
        .Add(ApplicableIdentifiers(searchExpression))
        .AddShareClassOrder(order)
        .SetMaxResults(pageSize)
        .List<ShareClassTrailingReturn>();
```

This is the SQL I'm seeing via NHibernate Profiler (though I've tidied it up a bit, and replaced all the items I'm selecting with `select top 25 *` to make it more readable):

```
SELECT   top 25 *
FROM     offline.ShareClassTrailingReturn this_
         inner join ShareManager.ShareClass shareclass1_
           on this_.SCTR_ShareClassId = shareclass1_.ShareClass_Id
         left outer join DCS.ShareClassInfo shareclass1_1_
           on shareclass1_.ShareClass_Id = shareclass1_1_.[ShareClassInfo_MSShareClassId]
WHERE    
    this_.SCTR_ShareClassId in 
    (
        SELECT this_0_.[Fund_ID] as y0_
        FROM   dbo.Fund this_0_
            inner join CAP.DataUniverse datauniver1_
              on this_0_.[Fund_TypeID] = datauniver1_.[DataUniverse_TypeId]
                 and this_0_.[Fund_CountryID] = datauniver1_.[DataUniverse_CountryID]
        WHERE  datauniver1_.[DataUniverse_SiteId] = 100 /* @p0 */
    )
    and this_.SCTR_ShareClassId in 
    (
        SELECT this_0_.ShareClass_Id as y0_
        FROM   dbo.vCalculationGroup this_0_
        WHERE  
            this_0_.PeerGroupId in (1,8)
            and this_0_.ClassificationId in (7,1)
    )
    and this_.SCTR_CurrencyId = 'GBP'
    and 
    (
        shareclass1_.ShareClass_MEX like '%axa%' 
        or shareclass1_.ShareClass_SEDOL like '%axa%'
        or shareclass1_1_.ShareClassInfo_RIC like '%axa%'
        or shareclass1_.ShareClass_ISIN like '%axa%'
        or shareclass1_.ShareClass_CUSIP like '%axa%'
    )
ORDER BY shareclass1_.ShareClass_Name asc
```

If I change the NHibernate criteria so that it doesn't do the select against the vCalculationGroup, i.e. if I remove this line:

```
.Add(LambdaSubquery.Property<ShareClassTrailingReturn>(x => x.ShareClass.Id).In(GetShareclassIdsInCalculationGroup(peerGroups, classificationTypes)))
```

or this from the SQL

```
    and this_.SCTR_ShareClassId in 
    (
        SELECT this_0_.ShareClass_Id as y0_
        FROM   dbo.vCalculationGroup this_0_
        WHERE  
            this_0_.PeerGroupId in (1,8)
            and this_0_.ClassificationId in (7,1)
    )
```

The query no longer times out. Does this mean that I need to do something with that View? Like Indexing or something?

**Could somebody please suggest how I can approach resolution of this issue?**

**Edit:** I should add that the query runs fine from SQL Server Management Studio, and returns after about 6 seconds. Though with that said, when I look at the execution plan, it reports that there's an Index missing on offline.ShareClassTrailingReturn. Is it likely that this could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely take a look at the indexing on the view if removing that part makes it work better. It would also be worth checking your connection timeout in your application. If you say it is working fine in Management Studio in six seconds, it could be that your application connection timeout is less than six seconds (or the default is less). Those would be good starting points.

It is worth trying to avoid a lot of nested subqueries in general. You have a lot in the SQL that is produced. Sometimes it is more efficient to write the SQL or HQL yourself, instead of using lots of complex joins in the Criteria or Linq NHibernate APIs. You are more likely to produce efficient SQL for the job!

Comment: Good advice, thanks. We resolved this by doing joins rather than `In<>()`'s